# Incomplete Delaunay triangulation

Tags: c++, opencv, convex-hull, delaunay

I'm using C++ and OpenCV to create a Delaunay triangle mesh from user-specified sample points on an image (which will then be extrapolated across the domain using the FEM for the relevant ODE).

Since the 4 corners of the (rectangular) image are in the list of vertices supplied to Subdiv2D, I expect the outer convex hull of the triangulation to trace the perimeter of the image. However, very frequently, there are missing elements around the outside.

Sometimes I can get the expected result by nudging the coordinates of certain points to avoid high aspect ratio triangles. But this is not a solution as in general the user most be able to specify any valid coordinates.

An example output is like this: [CV Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ModBS.png). Elements are in white with black edges. At the bottom and right edges, no triangles have been added, and you can see through to the black background.

How can I make the outer convex hull of the triangulation trace the image perimeter with no gaps please?

Here is a MWE (with a plotting function included):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

void DrawDelaunay(cv::Mat& image,cv::Subdiv2D& subdiv);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    // image dim
    int width=3440;
    int height=2293;
    
    // sample coords
    std::vector<int> x={0,width-1,width-1,0,589,1015,1674,2239,2432,3324,2125,2110,3106,3295,1298,1223,277,208,54,54,1749,3245,431,1283,1397,3166};
    std::vector<int> y={0,0,height-1,height-1,2125,1739,1154,817,331,143,1377,2006,1952,1501,872,545,812,310,2180,54,2244,2234,1387,1412,118,1040};

    // add delaunay nodes
    cv::Rect rect(0,0,width,height);
    cv::Subdiv2D subdiv(rect);
    for(size_t i=0;i<x.size();++i)
    {
        cv::Point2f p(x[i],y[i]);
        subdiv.insert(p);
    }
    
    // draw elements
    cv::Mat image(height,width,CV_8U);
    DrawDelaunay(image,subdiv);
    cv::resize(image,image,cv::Size(),0.3,0.3);
    cv::imshow("Delaunay",image);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

void DrawDelaunay(cv::Mat& image,cv::Subdiv2D& subdiv)
{
    std::vector<cv::Vec6f> elements;
    subdiv.getTriangleList(elements);
    std::vector<cv::Point> pt(3);

    for(size_t i=0;i<elements.size();++i)
    {
        // node coords
        cv::Vec6f t=elements[i];
        pt[0]=cv::Point(cvRound(t[0]),cvRound(t[1]));
        pt[1]=cv::Point(cvRound(t[2]),cvRound(t[3]));
        pt[2]=cv::Point(cvRound(t[4]),cvRound(t[5]));

        // element edges
        cv::Scalar black(0,0,0);
        cv::line(image,pt[0],pt[1],black,3);
        cv::line(image,pt[1],pt[2],black,3);
        cv::line(image,pt[2],pt[0],black,3);

        // element fill
        int nump=3;
        const cv::Point* pp[1]={&pt[0]};
        cv::fillPoly(image,pp,&nump,1,cv::Scalar(255,0,0));
    }
}
```

If relevant, I coded this in Matlab first where the Delaunay triangulation worked exactly as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a border around the 'cv::Rect rect' provided to cv::Subdiv2D, making it larger in width and height than the image (20% larger seems to work well).

Then instead of adding nodes to the corners of the image, I added 4 corner nodes and 4 edge nodes to the perimiter of this enlarged 'cv::Rect rect' variable which holds the Delaunay points.

This seems to solve the problem. I think what was happening was that if the user placed any samples near the edge of the image, it resulted in high aspect ratio triangles at the edges. This [ticket](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16763) suggests there is a bug around this in the OpenCV implementation of the Delaunay algorithm.

My solution hopefully means that corner and edge nodes are never too close to user samples, side-stepping the issue.

I haven't tested this extensively yet. I'm not sure how robust the solution will turn out to be. It has worked so far.

I'm still interested to know of other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your data points through the [Tinfour](https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour) project's demo application and got the results shown below.  It looks like your data is fine.  Unfortunately, the Tinfour project is written in Java and you're working in C++, so it will have limited value to you.

Since you plan on using Finite Element Methods, you might want to see whether there is any way you can run a Delaunay Refinement operation over your data to improve the geometry.  The skinny triangles sometimes lead to numerical issues when using FEM software.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In general, you are right that high AR triangles can cause numerical issues in the FEM. I'm using the fairly basic linear triangular elements for Poisson's equation, however. Provided they are not completely 'flat', they seem as robust as you get. Nevertheless, these high AR triangles are causing this implementation of the Delaunay algorithm problems. My latest refinement is to carpet the domain with a grid of fairly evenly spaced nodes (not sample locations), in addition to enlarging the meshed domain, and the triangles look much better.